# cannot clone a repo when running commnad in bash file in jenkins command shell but it works when I directly run in jenkins command shell

Tags: bash, git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am facing weird issue.
I run the following command in jenkins shell which has access to a repo.
I run an ansible command which part of it clones a repo as follows which runs directly in jenkins command shell.

```
ansible-playbook -i $INVENTORY_PATH $PLAYBOOK_PATH/backend.yml -vv --extra-vars '{"build_type":"jenkins_test", "BUILD_DIR":"'"$WORKSPACE"'","BUILD_NUMBER":"'"${BUILD_NUMBER}"'", "BRANCH":"develop"}'
```

So that runs very well and it clones the repo.
I changes the flow and added the above command in a bash file in another repo.
Then I clone that in jenkins and I run that sh file in jenkins commnad shell as follows.

```
 cd $WORKSPACE/test-jenkins

 ansible-playbook -i $INVENTORY_PATH $PLAYBOOK_PATH/backend.yml -vv --extra-vars '{"build_type":"jenkins_test", "BUILD_DIR":"'"$WORKSPACE"'","BUILD_NUMBER":"'"${BUILD_NUMBER}"'", "BRANCH":"develop"}'
```

and strangly I get the following:

```
"Cloning into 'some path'...\nHost key verification failed.\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.", "rc": 128, "stderr": "Cloning into 'some path'...\nHost key verification failed.\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n", "stderr_lines": ["Cloning into 'some path'...", "Host key verification failed.", "fatal: Could not read from remote repository.", "", "Please make sure you have the correct access rights", "and the repository exists."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Compare the environments of both your bash, and your jenkins command shell.  Most probably some variables are not set in your bash environment.

Comment: @Nic3500 so do you mean I should print the env var in both bash and execution shell and compare them?

Comment: You probably have a different ssh key in both environments. Compare the `~/.ssh/` folder and the `id_rsa*` files.

Comment: @Learner: yes indeed.